# Training a random forest with an imbalanced dataset with ranger, which parameter to use for weights?

Tags: r, random-forest, unbalanced-classes

I would like to train a random forest and I got an unbalanced dataset which could look like this:

| class | number of observations | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 |

In order to take the dataset imbalance into account I would like to use weights.

The r package [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf) (p. 16) has got the three parameters **sample.fraction**, **case.weights** and **class.weights** and I am not sure which one is the correct to use with the weights.  I would also be interested in an explanation when to use the other two parameters.

I guess the parameter  **sample.fraction** would be the right to use here.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample fraction just randomly selects a subset of rows per tree.

`class.weights` will be the most relevant one. It assigns a cost to each factor level for split evaluation and majority voting.
Whether it is necessary to reweight classes is the other question. That depends very much on the business goal.